# how to connect suiteCRM application to IDE

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have suiteCRM instance installed using google cloud/launcher. Its also connected to phpMyadmin. However i wanted to gain access to its directory structure that is PHP folder structure. Could someone suggest me how to connect this instance to IDE?